# empty double and float in printf and String.format

Tags: java, printf

In Java, when I supply a floating point variable to `printf` or `String.format`, it gives nothing. To illustrate, an example:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        double d = 123.456; 
        System.out.println("println: " + d + " " + (int) d);
        System.out.printf("printf as int: %d%n", (int) d);
        System.out.printf("printf with %%f: %f%n", d);
        System.out.printf("printf with %%e: %e%n", d);
        System.out.printf("printf with %%g: %g%n", d);
        System.out.printf("printf with %%a: %a%n", d);
    }
}
```

gives

```
in println: 123.456 123
in printf as int: 123
in printf with %f: 
in printf with %e: 
in printf with %g: 
in printf with %a:
```

as You can see, it does work with `println`, but it fails on printf. Same goes with `String.format`. If I supply width and precision, it does the same - gives nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I am using en_US.UTF-8 locale; 
I am not sure what version of Java I am using. What I know is: I compile it with gcc (gcj), version 4.7.2; And Have gcj JRE version 4.7.2 and OpenJDK JRE version 7u7-2.3.2a installed.; 
Edited the code. Now it is the whole code of the program. I wrote it as a small test program after I noticed these problems with floating point numbers in my other code.

Comment: I don't think you need double % sign

Comment: you're using `%` in your second `printf`, where you intend `%f`, but you should be seeing output for all of those.

Comment: The code runs you might have observation otherwise ie. println

Comment: The first `%a` should be `%f`, but like AmitD and pb2q said, the code runs.

Comment: Is this your whole code? Which Java version are you using? Which locale are you using? Try [Locale.ROOT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) explicitly.

Comment: @Banthar I edited my question to add this information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good chance it's a bug in GCJ. See here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=561685

Get rid of GCJ and use OpenJDK or Sun/OracleJDK.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code and my output. I don't see a problem.

```
package foo;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 123.456; 
    System.out.println("in println: " + d + " " + (int) d);
    System.out.printf("in printf as int: %d%n", (int) d);
    System.out.printf("in printf with %%f: %a%n", d);
    System.out.printf("in printf with %%e: %e%n", d);
    System.out.printf("in printf with %%g: %g%n", d);
    System.out.printf("in printf with %%a: %a%n", d);

  }

 }
```

Gives

```
in println: 123.456 123
in printf as int: 123
in printf with %f: 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p6
in printf with %e: 1.234560e+02
in printf with %g: 123.456
in printf with %a: 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p6
```

Comment: I would say as there is no problem this is the answer.